# How do I read from storage in Azure function using asynchronous methods

Tags: azure, async-await, azure-functions

I have made an Azure V2 function I want to call from a Logic App that converts a CSV-blob to JSON. This method works fine when running it locally in VS and calling it from a browser, but deploying it and calling it from Logic App does nothing.

It never returns anything to the Logic App. The Logic app retries a number of times and then fails.

Debugging it shows it calling DownloadTextAsync and then after a while the debugger catches again on the retry, and then again and again.

I tried to google this and found some articles about deadlocks, although there is no UI that could get blocked and tried to change it to:

```
var content = await blob.DownloadTextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I also tried to make the Function synchrounous and call:

```
var content = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
```

but neither one worked. What is wrong?

```
    [FunctionName("ConvertCSVToJSON")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        var containerName = GetEnvironmentVariable("RawDataStorageContainerName");
        var blobName = query["Path"];
        var accountName = GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobDataStorageAccountName");
        var accessKey = GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobDataStorageAccountAccessKey");
        var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accessKey + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        var storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var client = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        var content = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
        var json = ConvertCsvToJsonObject(content);

        return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"{json}");
    }
```

EDIT:
I also tried to add this code:
            CloudBlockBlob jsonBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName.Replace("csv","json"));
            await jsonBlob.UploadTextAsync(content);

running it locally creates a new blob, but running it from Logic App does not, so for some reason the read call never returns to the function if called from Logic app

Comment: Have you checked logs on Azure Function side? Go to kudu `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` to see function host logs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately it shows nothing. There are some rows from yesterday:

2019-02-07T13:41:25.543 [Error] Executed 'ConvertCSVToJSON' (Failed, Id=98a10c60-6be8-4b8f-a77a-0c37f1ab837e)
The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.

But those where attempts to call it with wrong parameter. There are no logs for today.

Comment: Have you directly called the Azure function in browser?

Comment: Yes, starting the function from VS and calling it from a browser works fine. 

Remote debugging and stepping shows execution entering the async call but it never returns from there.

So the code is right, but something with async is now causing the problem.

Comment: Hmm...I can confirm your code works in my test with logic app. Is there any firewall settings in your Storage account? Also how you do call the Function, use the built-in Azure Function action?

Comment: Yes, I use the Azure function action and it lets me choose the from a list. I use GET and empty body, and put a JSON with just one field called "Path" in the Queries field. All settings in the action are left at their default values.  
The run history gives this output. So 500 indicates internal server error, but there is no more data about it

{  
    "statusCode": 500,  
    "headers": {  
...   
    }  
}

Comment: Storage account is at the default firewall setting, Allow access from All networks. There are no virtual networks configured in my setup.  Everything is in the same location and resource group. The Logic app is triggered by an event grid trigger.

Comment: Have you added those app settings like `BlobDataStorageAccountName` in Application settings in Azure portal?

Comment: Well finally got this working. All the settings where there, but the one of the setting values had an extra character. This was caused by a typo in my Powershell script that deploys the Function from an ARM template. Of course this character was not present in my local settings file, that's why it worked from there. Strange that none of the commands threw an Exception, even when I remotely debugged it from VS. The execution just simply stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code, but in a misspelled setting value.